# use button to select variable

Tags: esp8266, button, variables

i have a need to use 3 buttons a a simple option/variable selector at sketch start up ...

Pretty much at startup , script must wait for button press ( one of 3 ) , when button is pressed , use that buttons predefined string value as a variable for the loop script further down .. if wanting to change the "variable" then a reboot is required ..

i know how to digital read in the buttons , but not sure how to

1) wait for one of the buttons to be pressed to then jump to main loop 
2) Associate a "string" variable to each button

thinking about it i suppose a If/Else loop will be required for the Input 'wait" and then just if the digital input (button) is pushed then continue .. am i correct ?

Ideas or better way to do it ?

Thx
Greg

Answer (score 2):

1) One solution is to create a function that loops repeatedly, eg `while(1)`, until one of the buttons is pressed. It then returns the button "number", eg 0,1 or 2.

2) In C you would usually remember the index into a string table. So one solution is to store the button number in a global variable and use it to index a "string array", something like `char * buttonStrings["B1","B2","B3"];` and to get the string for a button use `buttonStrings[buttonNumber];`

Answer (score 1):

When I am searching for something inside a loop, I find that the
simplest thing to do is to just `break` out of the loop once I found it.
This was frowned upon in the days when structured programming was a hot
thing, but as long as it makes things simpler, you should not be ashamed
to `break`:

```c++
const int button_pins[] = {2, 3, 4};
const char * const urls[] = {"foo.com", "bar.org", "baz.net"};
const char * url;  // the selected URL

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    // Configure input pins.
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pinMode(button_pins[i], INPUT_PULLUP);

    // Find first button pressed.
    int i;  // button index
    for (i = 0; ; i = i==2 ? 0 : i+1) {
        if (digitalRead(button_pins[i]) == LOW)
            break;
    }

    // The button index selects the URL.
    url = urls[i];

    Serial.print("Selected URL: ");
    Serial.println(url);
}

void loop() {}
```

The `for` loop above is written as an endless loop (no end condition).
The expression `i = i==2 ? 0 : i+1` means: “if `i` is `2`, make it `0`,
otherwise make it `i+1`”. In other words, we are endlessly looping `i`
over 0, 1 and 2.

Now, it may well happen that you actually do not care about which button
was pressed once you have selected the proper URL. In this case, you can
use the URL pointer as a “flag” that tells you when you can end the
loop:

```c++
// First button pressed selects the URL.
for (int i = 0; !url; i = i==2 ? 0 : i+1) {
    if (digitalRead(button_pins[i]) == LOW)
        url = urls[i];
}
```

Where `!url` means “the URL has not been found”. This works because the
C runtime initializes `url` to zero, which is interpreted as `false` in
boolean context.

**Addendum**: If you are likely to add new button/URL pairs, you can
make this easier by structuring the list as an array of structs:

```c++
const struct {
    int pin;          // pin number
    const char *url;  // associated URL
} buttons[] = {
    {2, "foo.com"},
    {3, "bar.org"},
    {4, "baz.net"}
    // etc. just add to this list as needed.
};
const size_t button_count = sizeof buttons / sizeof buttons[0];
```

Then the search becomes:

```c++
for (int i = 0; !url; i = i==button_count-1 ? 0 : i+1) {
    if (digitalRead(buttons[i].pin) == LOW)
        url = buttons[i].url;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this. The comments in the program explain quite well.

```
const int buttons[3] = {2,3,4}; // buttons pins

int butStatus = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttons[0], INPUT); // declaring pins as inputs
  pinMode(buttons[1], INPUT);
  pinMode(buttons[2], INPUT);

  while(butStatus<=0) //waiting for a button to be pressed
  {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) //running trough the 3 buttons
    {
      if(digitalRead(buttons[i]) == HIGH)
      {
        butStatus = i+1; //set variable to the button that has been turned on
      }

      else
      {
        butStatus = 0; //if there is no button press, keep the variable at 0
      }
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  //variable butStatus is now equal to the button that has been pressed
}
```

Comment: Thanks , this looks good .. one question , for the variable .. i require the variables to be URL strings  (example www.google.com) , how can i map this ?? so something like button 1 = www.google.com , button 2 - www.yahoo.com , button 3 = somesite.com

Comment: use `string urls[3] = {"www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com","www.somesite.com"}`. Then you can call `string something = urls[butStatus];`.

Comment: perfect :-) let me go play :-)

Comment: Better make that `string something = urls[butStatus-1];` butStatus is 0 for no button or 1-3 for a button pressed, you need to subtract one to get back to a zero based array index.

Comment: Your code can only sense the last button.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, mind explaining a bit...

Comment: If button 2 is not pressed, you `butStatus = 0;` and stay in the loop.

Comment: Did you see this? `butStatus = i+1`

Comment: canadiancyborg,  @EdgarBonet is correct: in your code as shown, the only way the `while(butStatus<=0)` loop can exit is if the third button is pressed, regardless of the state of the other two buttons. Get rid of the silly-error code `else { butStatus = 0; }`.  Also, in `string urls[3] ...` perhaps you meant to capitalize `string`